# Select and join from to tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, join

I have **users** and **message_threads** tables.

```
    thread_message tables

    Id | ToUserId | FromUserId
----------------------------------
     1 |    1     |      2
     2 |    2     |      3


    users Table

        Id | Name 
    -----------------
         1 |    Ali    
         2 |    Mahdi
         3 |    Hossein
```

`Ali` want to get all records from `thread_message` that his `Id` is in the one of`ToUserId` or `FromUserId` and get Name of other user pair(In this example `Mahdi`).
Ali sends his `Id` when request records.

What's **SELECT** & **JOIN** statement for this problem?

In this example result should be

```
(Id ,ToUserId, FromUserId, Name)

(1, 1, 2, Mahdi)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  (select t.*, u.Name from thread_message t left join users u on FromUserId=u.Id where ToUserId=1) 
union 
  (select t.*, u.Name from thread_message t left join users u on ToUserId=u.Id where FromUserId=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T.Id, 
         T.ToUserId, 
         T.FromUserId,
        (CASE WHEN T.ToUserId = tu.Id THEN fu.Name WHEN T.FromUserId = tu.Id THEN tu.Name ELSE '' END) Name
FROM thread_message T 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users tu ON T.ToUserId = tu.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN users fu ON T.FromUserId = tu.Id
WHERE 1 IN (T.ToUserId, T.FromUserId);
```

Comment: @Ali fu and tu are the alias name of users tables. fu is joined with thread_message with fromuserid column where as tu is joined with touserid column

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION t.FromUserId does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Another approach does all the comparisons in the `where` (or `on`) clause:

```
select tm.*
from thread_message tm cross join
     (select id
      from users
      where name = 'Ali'
     ) x
where x.id in (tm.ToUserId, tm.FromUserId);
```

EDIT:

If you have the id of 'Ali' then the answer is even simpler:

```
select tm.*
from thread_message tm 
where $id in (tm.ToUserId, tm.FromUserId);
```

Comment: It doens't send Ali name for where clause, sends Id of Ali